# Autofit table column with booktabs

Tags: tables, lyx, columns, booktabs

### Background

Using `booktabs` produces the top table in the following image:

[image]

Both tables reside in floats, but even when outside of the float the same result is produced. The **Application** and **Version** columns are too wide.

LyX seems to generate the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{4.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{4.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{4.5cm}l}
```

The preamble is straightforward:

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}

\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

The commands `\toprule()` and `\\\midrule %` and `\\\bottomrule %` are applied directly to the table.

### Questions

1. Without hand-massaging each table, how can the columns be made to auto-fit? 
   (I could not find how to control column width in the `booktabs` documentation.)
2. How can the top-, mid-, and bottom-rules be applied across all tables in the document, automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the Preamble to the following:

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref,table]{xcolor}
   ```

   % Table colours
   \colorlet{tableheader}{LightGray!80}
   \colorlet{zebra}{LightGray!40}

   \hypersetup{
       colorlinks=false,
       pdfborder={0 0 0},
   }

   \let\originaltable\table
   \let\endoriginaltable\endtable
   \renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]{%
     \originaltable[#1]
     \centering}%
     {\endoriginaltable}
2. In the settings for each column, ensure the Width is blank. (Any numeric value will attempt to fit the columns to that width.)